# Assigning probability to membership in an NP-complete language

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, p-vs-np, average-case-complexity

### Motivation

Assuming $\mathsf{P}\ne\mathsf{NP}$, it is impossible to efficiently decide membership in an NP-complete language. I would like to assign *probability* to such membership, in some sense.

### Definitions

The following definitions use the approach to average-case complexity given in e.g. O. Goldreich "[Computational Complexity](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/Computational_Complexity.html?id=EuguvA-w5OEC&redir_esc=y)" chapter 10.

Consider $(L, X_n)$ an average-case decision problem where $L$ is a language and $X_n$ is a family of random variables which can be sampled by an algorithm with polynomial running time.

Consider $A$ an algorithm computing for each input string $x$ an infinite binary fraction in $[0, 1]$ (informally regarded as a probability). We call such algorithms "estimators". $A$ is called *efficient* when the time of computing $k$ digits of $A(x)$ is bounded by $p(|x|, 2^k)$ with $p$ polynomial.

Define the *error function* to be

$$\epsilon_n(A; L):=-E_{X_n}[\chi_L(x)\ln A(x) + (1-\chi_L(x))\ln(1-A(x))]$$

where $\chi_L(x)$ is the characteristic function of $L$. It is easy to see that assuming $\mathsf{sampP}\ne\mathsf{sampNP}$, for $(L, X_n)$ which is $\mathsf{sampNP}$-complete there is a polynomial $q$ s.t.

$$\forall n \exists m > n:\epsilon_m(A; L) > \frac{1}{|q(m)|}$$

Define $A$ to be *optimal* for $(L, X_n)$ when it is efficient and for any efficient $B$ and polynomial $r$:

$$\forall n >> 0:\epsilon_n(A; L) - \epsilon_n(B; L) < \frac{1}{|r(n)|}$$

### Question

> Assuming $\mathsf{sampP}\ne\mathsf{sampNP}$ (and other conjectures if necessary), does $A$ exist which is optimal for an $\mathsf{sampNP}$-complete problem?

### Observations

#### Reductions

Let's call a Karp-reduction $f$ of $(L, X_n)$ to $(M, Y_n)$ *semi-invertible* when there exists $g: \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace^* \rightarrow \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace^* \cup \lbrace \bot \rbrace$ computable in polynomial time s.t.

$$\forall x: g(f(x))=x$$

$$\forall y: g(y) \ne \bot \rightarrow f(g(y))=y$$

Given $A$ optimal for $(M, Y_n)$ and $f$ a semi-invertible reduction of $(L, X_n)$ to $(M, Y_n)$, $A \circ f$ is optimal for $(L, X_n)$. In particular, if $(M, Y_n)$ is $\mathsf{sampNP}$-complete s.t. the reductions can be chosen semi-invertible (such $(M, Y_n)$ exists since examining the construction of a complete problem in [Ben-David et al](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PS/aver.ps) we see the reductions are semi-invertible), we get optimal algorithms for all problems in $\mathsf{sampNP}$. In particular, $A$ yields an average-case polynomial time solution for any problem formulated as a problem in $\mathsf{sampNP}$ which is "secretly" in $\mathsf{sampP}$. This is similar to the properties of Levin search, but Levin search only solves instances with a positive answer.

#### Uniqueness

Consider $A$, $B$ estimators for $(L, X_n)$. Define the "metric"

$$\delta_n(A, B; L) := E_{X_n}[\chi_L |\ln{A} - \ln{B}| + (1-\chi_L) |\ln{(1-A)} - \ln{(1-B)}|]$$

If $\delta_n(A, B; L)$ vanishes for large $n$ with superpolynomial speed, then $\epsilon_n(A; L) - \epsilon_n(B; L)$ also vanished for large $n$ with superpolynomial speed.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both optimal. Then it can be seen that $\delta_n(A, B; L)$ vanishes for large $n$ with superpolynomial speed (via considering $\frac{A+B}{2}$ and using the convexity of the logarithm). So optimal estimators are unique up to "small" deviations.

Comment: Computation $\mapsto$ Computational $\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: How is it "easy to see that"? $\:$ I only see how to show "for infinitely many $n$", $\hspace{1.37 in}$ rather than "for sufficiently large $n$". $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: You're absolutely right, the claim as it stands is false e.g. you can take a complete language which contains strings of only even length. Thx!

Comment: Very interesting Q! Possibly related to resource-bounded martingales and resource-bounded measure, e.g. https://doi.org/10.1137/0219076 and https://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~jhitchco/bib/rbm.shtml. Point being that if you can assign a *good enough* probability of each $x$ be in a language, then that language is not p-random. So if you *cannot* assign a good enough probability to each x for an NP-complete language, it would separate P from NP (amongst other consequences). But $\mu_p(NP) \neq 0$ is not known to follow from $P \neq NP$ alone. Would be interesting if it were directly related to $sampNP$!